# How to fix the error "Rename refactoring can't be applied in this context" in Netbeans?

Tags: html, netbeans, refactoring

I'm currently working on a HTML5 projects in netbeans and wanted to change a variable name with multiple occurrence. However, when I clicked refactor and then rename, the IDE tells me that:

> Rename refactoring can't be applied in this context.

So is it possible to refactor variable names in HTML5 projects in Netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript refactoring options are very limited, typically it works only in context of single file and you can invoke it by placing cursor on the target variable/function and pressing Ctrl+R (sorry, not sure about the shortcut on Mac) and then typing a new name. This is not full refactoring, only "limited rename" and again, it will rename variables only in given file, not the whole project.

Please note that in NetBeans if you open Refactor from the main menu, there is also Rename action with the same shortcut displayed but the shortcut is actually doing something else than the menu item.

Comment: @lader thank you so much for the heads up! Its so annoying that netbeans lacks this very basic function. Do you happen to know which IDE has full refactoring function with html5 project? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I don't know about WebStorm, but I imagine "full" refactoring can be pretty difficult/impossible to support since you would need to "run" (evaluate) all the JavaScript code in order to know how the context - JS is dynamic language with a plenty of ways to declare something and I can't imagine IDE would be 100% able to cover them all (maybe with some help of JSDoc it would be better)